# value recovery using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a concern for recovering value contained in a form (pop-up) in a field of another form (php), the collect value in the field must be in the form of a character string array. when I test my page, the result I got in my field is an array of (undefined: undefined: undefined: ..........) Here is my code:

in PHP:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label>Quantité & Taille*:</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" data-target="#tailleModal" onclick="jQuery('#tailleModal').modal('toggle');return false;">Quantité & Taille</button>
  </div>
   <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="tailleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Quantité & Taille</h5>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
                 </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++): ?>
                       <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                         <label for="taille <?php echo $i ;?>">Taille:</label>
                         <input type="text" name="taille <?php echo $i ;?>" id="taille <?php echo $i ;?>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                         <label for="taille <?php echo $i ;?>">Quantité:</label>
                         <input type="number" name="quantite <?php echo $i ;?>" value="" min="0" id="quantite <?php echo $i ;?>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updatetaille();jQuery('#tailleModal').modal('toggle');return false;">Enregistrer Modification</button>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="tailles">Quantité & Taille précédent:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tailles" id="tailles" value="<?php echo ((isset($_POST['tailles']))? $_POST['tailles']:'') ;?>" readonly>
  </div>
```

With Ajax

```js
function updatetaille(){
    var i,taillecaract='';
    var taille=$('#taille'+i).val();
    var quantite=$('#quantite'+i).val();
    for(var i=1;i<=12;i++){
        if (taille!='') {
          taillecaract+=taille+':'+quantite+',';
        }
      }
      $('#tailles').val(taillecaract);
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When I do what you do, the undefined error: undefined is displayed. I show you the result using image[img of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGSIM.png) when I press "Enregistrer Modification"the result displays undefined: undefined ...[img of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuftt.png)
thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In your php, where you set ids, like this

```
id="quantite <?php echo $i ;?>"
```

remove the space, like this

```
id="quantite<?php echo $i ;?>"
```

That should help, because in your javascript you have jquery using selectors like this

```
var taille=$('#taille'+i).val();
var quantite=$('#quantite'+i).val();
```

with no space